# Take input in a function, divide the array in equal parts and print child array with highest value Python 3.6

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function which will take array as an input.
The array will always be divisible by 4. The array needs to be split into 4 parts equally.
Let's call these 4 arrays parts "One" "Two" "Three" "Four".
The array name needs to be the output which has the maximum difference between it's any 2 elements:
e.g

```
ONE [2 ,-3 , 3]
TWO [1 ,10, 8]
THREE [2 ,5, 13]
FOUR [-5, 3 ,-18]
```

The output should be "Four" because -18--5 = 21 which is the maximum.

```
import numpy as np

def solution(T):
    arr = T
    newarr = np.array_split(arr, 4)
    print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, newarr)))
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you want our help with? Don't make us run your code to see how it fails -- show the failure in the question itself.

Comment: (if the problem is not a failure but a specific aspect of the spec you don't know how to implement, say that too, and show anything you _tried_ to do to implement that aspect)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will print `[ -5   3 -18]`, which is the sub-array that has the highest difference between its largest and smallest number.

```
import numpy as np

def solution(T):
    arr = T
    newarr = np.array_split(arr, 4)
    arrayIdx = np.argmax(np.amax(newarr, axis=1)-np.amin(newarr, axis=1))
    return newarr[arrayIdx]

    
array =  [2 ,-3 , 3, 1 ,10, 8, 2 ,5, 13, -5, 3 ,-18]
print(solution(array))
```